# I need help with tackling this proof that set $\mathbb Q$ of rationals is a $F_\sigma$ set

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Show the set $\mathbb Q$ of rationals is a $F_\sigma$ set

I am using Topology without Tears by Morris

**Thoughts on it**

$\mathbb Q$ is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb R$.

I know $\mathbb Q$ is countably infinite.

Since $\mathbb Q$ is countably infinite we can form a countable

union of such sets {$S_a$}{$a\in  \mathbb N$}

Thus $\mathbb Q$ is $F_\sigma$ set

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just because it is a countable set, and each point forms a closed set.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$1).\ $ Take $r\in \mathbb Q$ and an arbitrary open non-degenerate interval $(a,b)\ni r$. What "kind" of points are contained in $(a,b)?$

$2).\ $ Repeat $1).$ for $\mathbb Q^c$, the complement of $\mathbb Q.$

$3).\ $ Note that points are closed in $\mathbb R$ (why?). Now, use the definition of an $F_{\sigma}$ set together with a suitable property of $\mathbb Q.$

Comment: I know Q is countably infinite and r=a/b ,a,b$\in$ N

Comment: Ok...and points are closed, so...